# Sitecore: How to check the field with type DateTime is current month or not?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

I have an item named `Event` with field name `Start Date` with type `DateTime`. 
I want to check if the value of this field is current month or not?

Some thing like:

```
if(Event["Start Date"] == DateTime.Now.Month.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
```

But the above code always return me false. I have printed the value inside the field and it is `20150916T000000`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to first convert the date/time value to a .NET DateTime object. Try this code:

```cs
DateTime startDate = Sitecore.DateUtil.IsoDateToDateTime(Event["Start Date"]);

if(startDate.Month == DateTime.UtcNow.Month)
{
    // ...
}
```